# How to get data from Sharepoint list(s) and then insert it into SQL table using C# console app

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Background:

I am doing all this with SSOM (Sever side object model) in C# console app.
And I have a connection to and empty database which will be initialy populated and than updated as needed.

On SharePoint server there are a couple lists among which there is a "List Of Headers" that contains the name of all other lists. Other lists are catalogs of articles.

Headers List contains around 40 fields or so (Title, TypeOfCatalog, CatalogName, CatalogID,... so on)

Other Catalog Lists contain around 300 fields (CatalogId, ArticlePrice, ArticleName,... and so on)

Here's the code from the class i use:

```
 public class SharePointProduction
 {
    private static XYZ_Entity _context = new XYZ_Entity();

    public static void Main()
    {           

        string siteURL = "http://somesite.local/sites/promo_tool";          

        try
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteURL))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {          

                    GetSharePointCatalogHeaders(web);

                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            PrintErrorSharepointConnection();
            PrintPressKeyToExit();
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

GetSharePointCatalogHeaders METHOD -----------------

```
private static SPListItemCollection GetSharePointCatalogHeaders(SPWeb web)
    {

        var catalogHeaderList = web.Lists.TryGetList("Headers List");

        if (catalogHeaderList == null) throw new Exception("Unable to get catalog headers used for checking status of catalogs");

        var catalogHeaderItems = catalogHeaderList.GetItems("Id", "_x0160_ifra_x0020_artikla", "Naziv_x0020_artikla", "Katalog_x002f_ID", "Status_x0020_kataloga", "Datum_x0020_po_x010d_etka_x0020_");

        return catalogHeaderItems;
    }
```

So far, that's what I got.

I need to update Headers List in one table in database called "Headers", and other lists (Article Catalogs) to a "Catalogs" table.

To be clearer (I do apologize, English is my second language):

Comment: So, you need to write code to store the values in the database. Do you have an existing database? Do you access it already, and if so how? What kind of database is it?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Those items already come from a SQL Server databases. A List isn't a database table though. You don't need that list of list names "table" at all. All items are already available at the web level. If you use the correct method with a CAML query you could get the data as a DataTable BUT you'll still have to handle multiple values etc. You could filter by content type and get all relevant items from the entire web

Comment: Yes, I need to write a code that will read from Sharepoint lists and store it into database. I have a base on Microsoft SQL Server, created with VS 2019. For now i have a "Headers" table with all corresponding colums which exist in SharePoint list "Headers List". 

Connection to database is created with ADO.NET entity data model

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear but, a simple solution will be to export the SharePoint list in excel and then import that data into SQL table using SQL management studio,

But still, if you want to go by C#, then you can get all list items using below code and then insert into the SQL table

```
using ( SPSite site = new SPSite ("http://moss/sites/yousitename"))
{

  SPWeb myWeb = site.OpenWeb();
  SPList target = myWeb.Lists["YourListName"];
  SPListItems items = list.Items;
  myWeb.Dispose();
 }
```

Comment: Both options are anything but simple. SharePoint isn't a database. Exporting to Excel only exports a specific view and only for a limited number of records. The contents will be the display text, not the actual data. As for accessing list items through `Items`, it's a *very* slow process

Comment: But it's possible.

Comment: I am required to use Server side object model with C# console app. I need to get the item data from lists from SharePoint with console app, and than insert that same data into a database on some other server.

Answer (score 0):

The following code for your reference.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://somesite.local/sites/promo_tool"))
            {
                using (SPWeb myWeb = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList target = myWeb.Lists["Headers List"];
                    SPListItemCollection items = target.GetItems();
                    DataTable dt = items.GetDataTable();

                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        string consString = "SQL Connection String";
                        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
                        {
                            using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                            {
                                sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Table1";
                                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ID", "ID");
                                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("_x0160_ifra_x0020_artikla", "_x0160_ifra_x0020_artikla");
                                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Naziv_x0020_artikla", "Naziv_x0020_artikla");
                                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Katalog_x002f_ID", "Katalog_x002f_ID");
                                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Status_x0020_kataloga", "Status_x0020_kataloga");
                                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Datum_x0020_po_x010d_etka_x0020_", "Datum_x0020_po_x010d_etka_x0020_");
                                con.Open();
                                sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                                con.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

We can also use PowerShell to achieve it, the following article with PowerShell for your reference.

[Export SharePoint List Data to SQL Server Table using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/06/export-sharepoint-list-data-to-sql-server-table-using-powershell.html)

If you use SharePoint Online or access SharePoint list in client side, we can also use CSOM C# to achieve it.

[Archive SharePoint List Items to SQL Database Using CSOM](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/archive-sharepoint-list-items-to-sql-database-using-csom-pa/)